# No rounded edges in IE in Bootstrap

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, twitter-bootstrap, compatibility

Rounded edges in the buttons and badges shows rectangle in IE 8. I am using bootstrap button and badges. Is there a fix to  this. Anybody running into similar issue?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no proper fix, IE8 and below (later versions should support roundec corners) simply do not support the `border-radius` CSS3 property so you get a rectangle on certain elements instead of rounded ones. A couple of things you can try is including a .HTC script file that emulates such effects in older versions of IE, such as the [IE-CSS3](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/) project or (the more complete i believe) [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Check this thread from bootstrap Git:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1467

The following CSS selector works:

```
    border-radius: 0 \0/IE89;
```

Comment: This does not add rounded corners to IE 8. In fact, this does the opposite and resets the border radius to 0 for IE.